# Division of polynomial with multiple variable using synthetic division

Tags: polynomials

How to divide polynomials with multiple variables ? More precisely, let f be a polynomial of the form :

$f= \sum_{p1=0}^{n1} \sum_{p2=0}^{n2} \sum_{p3=0}^{n3} a_{p1,p2,p3}.x^{p1}.y^{p2}.z^{p3} = \prod_{j=1}^n (1+x^{a_j}.y^{b_j}.z^{c_j})$

where the exponents $a, b$ and  $c$ are vectors of strictly positive integers, 
and g is given by
$g= (1+x^{a_i}.y^{b_i}.z^{c_i})$

**I am looking for expressing the quotient $q=f/g$ using only $a_{p1,p2,p3}$.** 
I was able to divide polynomials similar to $f$ with unique variable using synthetic division. **Can synthetic division be used to divide polynomials with more than one variable?**

Thanks.

Comment: Would it not be easier in this specific setup to multiply the other factors with the divisor left out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, synthetic division in multiple variables is not well defined since the notion of remainder is not unique. In Gröbner basis theory, one defines for that purpose a "monomial order" that then allows to reduce multivariate polynomials like univariate polynomials and to determine minimal generating sets for ideals.

---

If one knows the remainder, which is zero here, and the final degree structure, as in this case, one can use one of Schönhages tricks, division by multiplication. To divide $f$ by $g=1+x^ay^bz^c$, multiply successively f by $1-x^ay^bz^c$, $1+(x^ay^bz^c)^2$, $1+(x^ay^bz^c)^4$, $1+(x^ay^bz^c)^8$ etc. until the degree of $(x^ay^bz^c)^{2^k}$ is outside of the degree range of the quotient. Then the lower degree terms of this product form the quotient.

Comment: What do you mean by the notion of the remainder is not unique? Since synthetic division is impossible, what do you suggest to compute the quotient s coefficients?

Comment: You can do division, but you have to fix a monomial order first. For a remainder of zero this is not that crucial, but nonzero remainders depend on monomial orders.

Comment: Let me see if I get the idea. Consider q=1, you have suggested to design an iterative algorithm, and during each iteration, q is multiplied by $(1+x^ay^bz^c)$ ie. at iteration t, $q =q*(1+x^ay^bz^c)$ until the degree of q becomes larger than the expected degree of the quotient. If I got it right, please let me remind you that the exponent a, b and c are different. More precisely, $f=\prod_{j=1}^n (1+x^{a_j}.y^{b_j}.z^{c_j})$ not $f=(1+x^ay^bz^c)^n$

Comment: If $q=1$, then $f=g=1+x^ay^bz^c$, so that $f\cdot (1-x^ay^bz^c)=1-(x^ay^bz^c)^2$ and the degree of the square is outside the degree bounds of the expected quotient, or indeed outside of the degree bounds of $f$ itself. So collecting all small degree terms just leaves $q=1$. Perhaps I should have written $(A,B,C)$ as shorts for $(a_i,b_i,c_i)$ in $g$.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused. Could please show me your idea  through an example? let $f=(1+x^2y).(1+x^3y^2).(1+xy^6)$ and $g=(1+x^2y)$, so $q=(1+x^3y^2).(1+xy^6)=x^4y^8+x^3y^2+xy^6+1$. As you pointed,STEP 1 $f= (1-x^2y)*(1+x^2y)=1-x^4y^2$, STEP 2, $f=f*(1+(x^2y)^2)$ , and then multiplying by $1+(x^2y)^4, 1+(x^2y)^8,...$, am I correct?

Comment: No. Your $f$ remains as given, I'd expect fully expanded. Then the largest total degree in $f$ is 16, so we need at least a power of 6 for $x^2y$ to be clearly ahead of it. Thus you compute $f*(1-x^2y)*(1+(x^2y)^2)*(1+(x^2y)^4)=q+O((x^2y)^8)$.

Comment: I got it, but this trick has one drawback, it requires a lot of computation. Thanks for the help.